# Production AdMob Banner Ad doesn't load oniOS

Tags: ios, admob, production

While I was making my iOS app, I used test AdMob AppID and AdUnitID.

Test ads showed up every time.

Today I made an AdMob account and got the production AppID and AdUnitID.

I copied them and replaced the test ones in my app.

I archived the app so to use the *Release* settings in XCode.

Then I uploaded it to AppStore.

However, when I download the app from TestFlight no ads are shown.

What am I missing?

P.S.
- GoogleAds framework is up to date
- AdMob account is filled with the required info.

***AppDelegate***

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: <AdMob AppID>)
```

***ViewController***

```
bannerAd.adUnitID = <AdMob adUnitID>
bannerAd.rootViewController = self
bannerAd.load(GADRequest())
```

Comment: Can you share your AdMob code inside of your AppDelegate and View Controller(s)?

Comment: Please, keep in mind that Test Ads were showing every time. I only changed the two IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Per [Admob Help](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en):

> When apps are newly registered with AdMob, it takes some time and a few ad requests to allow inventory to build. Because of this, you may not see live impressions immediately.
>
> Once your app is making more requests, you should see more consistent results. Please note that test ads operate through the same channels as live ads. Being able to return a test ad ensures that your application is communicating properly with our network.

I would say wait 24-48 hours to start seeing live ads, depending on your region.

Comment: Did waiting 48 hours fix this for you? I have the same problem, but have waited 6 days so far. I posted the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237868/admob-on-ios-no-ad-to-show